# Unable to query after importing sample data

Tags: cnosdb

Importing data into the cnsodb example, but no results were found in the query.

### Reproduction steps:

1. Setup cnosdb instance

```bash
 docker run --name cnosdb -d -p 31007:31007 cnosdb/cnosdb:2.2.0 cnosdb run -M singleton --config /etc/cnosdb/cnosdb.conf
```

2. Download sample data

```
wget https://dl.cnosdb.com/sample/oceanic_station.txt
```

3. Connect to the client and import data.

```
cnosdb-cli -H <host> -P <port>
\w oceanic_station.txt
```

### Actual results

```
public ❯ show tables;
+-------+
| Table |
+-------+
| sea   |
| air   |
| wind  |
+-------+
Query took 0.003 seconds.
public ❯ select * from air limit 1;
Query took 0.026 seconds.
public ❯ select * from sea limit 1;
Query took 0.018 seconds.
public ❯ select * from wind limit 1;
Query took 0.022 seconds.
```

### Expected results

```
public ❯ show tables;
+-------+
| Table |
+-------+
| sea   |
| air   |
| wind  |
+-------+
Query took 0.003 seconds.
public ❯ select * from air limit 1;
+---------------------+------------+----------+-------------+------------+
| time                | station    | pressure | temperature | visibility |
+---------------------+------------+----------+-------------+------------+
| 2023-02-02T15:00:00 | XiaoMaiDao | 79.0     | 66.0        | 75.0       |
+---------------------+------------+----------+-------------+------------+
Query took 0.026 seconds.
public ❯ select * from sea limit 1;
+---------------------+------------+-------------+
| time                | station    | temperature |
+---------------------+------------+-------------+
| 2023-02-02T15:00:00 | XiaoMaiDao | 73.0        |
+---------------------+------------+-------------+
Query took 0.018 seconds.
public ❯ select * from wind limit 1;
+---------------------+------------+-----------+-------+
| time                | station    | direction | speed |
+---------------------+------------+-----------+-------+
| 2023-01-14T16:00:00 | XiaoMaiDao | 56.0      | 57.0  |
+---------------------+------------+-----------+-------+
Query took 0.022 seconds.
```

Comment: Can you share the log from api metahost:port/debug?